# How do we choose a random element in an array?

Tags: arrays, random

```
{
String[] hi = new String[5] ;  
strArray[0] = ("Hello") ;
strArray[1] = ("hola") ;
strArray[2] = ("nihao") ;
strArray[3] = ("hallo") ;
strArray[4] = ("aloha") ; 
{
```

How would I use a random function to choose one of the strings in the array so it's usable?

Comment: Dude...really?  That code isn't even close to compile-ready.  Google "rand".

Comment: Use your language's random integer generating function to generate a random number in `[0,1,2,3,4]` and pick the corresponding string...

Comment: Might be Java, in that case check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java?rq=1

Comment: spartygw - just one part of my code, don't worry haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF** this is java you could use

```
String[] hi = new String[] { "Hello", "Hola", "Nihao" };
Random rand = new Random();
System.out.println(hi[rand.nextInt(hi.length)]);
```